# Center Text within TD with inline IMG

Tags: javascript, css, html

The desired effect is to have centered-middle text within a table cell while the alignment thereof is not affected by an inline image that is right-middle within the same table cell. See link to problem diagram to see what I mean. The "solution" denotes the desired effect while "problem" denotes what the code is currently doing. Much appreciated for the assistance.

[image: Problem Diagram]

```
// Create table cell for job priority.
var jobPriority  = jobRow.insertCell(3);
var jobPriorityValue = Number(document.getElementById('job-priority').value);
jobPriority.id = 'jobPriorityCell'+ jobIndex;
var jobPriorityID = 'jobPriority' + jobIndex;
var jobPriorityIconID = 'jobPriorityIcon' + jobIndex;
var jobPriorityNumberID = 'jobPriorityNumber' + jobIndex;
var jobPrioritySave = false;
jobPriority.innerHTML = '<dt id="' + jobPriorityID + '">' + jobPriorityValue + '</dt><input type="number" id="' + jobPriorityNumberID + '"><img src="images/push_mouseout.svg" id="' + jobPriorityIconID + '" class="icon3">';
document.getElementById(jobPriorityID).style.margin = '0 auto';
document.getElementById(jobPriorityID).style.display = 'inline';
document.getElementById(jobPriorityNumberID).style.cssFloat = 'left';
document.getElementById(jobPriorityNumberID).style.marginLeft = '3px';
document.getElementById(jobPriorityNumberID).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById(jobPriorityNumberID).style.width = '38px';
document.getElementById(jobPriorityNumberID).style.textAlign = 'center';
document.getElementById(jobPriorityNumberID).min = '1';
document.getElementById(jobPriorityNumberID).max = '99';
document.getElementById(jobPriorityIconID).style.marginRight = '3px';
document.getElementById(jobPriorityIconID).style.cssFloat = 'right';
document.getElementById(jobPriorityIconID).style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById(jobPriority.id).addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    if (!jobPrioritySave)
        document.getElementById(jobPriorityIconID).style.visibility = 'visible';
});
document.getElementById(jobPriority.id).addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
    if (!jobPrioritySave)
        document.getElementById(jobPriorityIconID).style.visibility = 'hidden';
});
document.getElementById(jobPriorityIconID).addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    if (!jobPrioritySave)
        document.getElementById(jobPriorityIconID).src = menuImages.push.image.mouseover.src;
    else
        document.getElementById(jobPriorityIconID).src = menuImages.save.image.mouseover.src;
        document.getElementById(jobPriorityIconID).style.cursor = 'pointer';
});
document.getElementById(jobPriorityIconID).addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
    if (!jobPrioritySave)
        document.getElementById(jobPriorityIconID).src = menuImages.push.image.mouseout.src;
    else
        document.getElementById(jobPriorityIconID).src = menuImages.save.image.mouseout.src;
});
document.getElementById(jobPriorityIconID).addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (!jobPrioritySave) {
        jobPrioritySave = true;
        document.getElementById(jobPriorityNumberID).value = jobPriorityValue;
        document.getElementById(jobPriorityID).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(jobPriorityNumberID).style.display = 'initial';
        document.getElementById(jobPriorityIconID).style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById(jobPriorityIconID).src = menuImages.save.image.mouseout.src;
    }
    else {
        jobPrioritySave = false;
        jobPriorityValue = document.getElementById(jobPriorityNumberID).value;
        document.getElementById(jobPriorityID).innerText = jobPriorityValue;
        document.getElementById(jobPriorityID).style.display = 'initial';
        document.getElementById(jobPriorityNumberID).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(jobPriorityIconID).style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById(jobPriorityIconID).src = menuImages.push.image.mouseout.src;
    }
});
```

Comment: Absolutely positioning the image would be the easiest way IMHO ...

Comment: `document.getElementById(jobPriorityID).style` all this calls are TOO heavy for browser. Try to save a link to this object and change it's attributes like `var styles = document.getElementById(jobPriorityID).style; styles.margin = '0 auto'` It'll make your code work faster and also make it more readable.

Comment: **If image has a known size**, then no need to use javascript, you may use a pseudo element of same size to balance the layout or  use text-indent if the image stands aside one line only : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pLNXgE

Comment: @AndrewEvt Or even better... manage styles in a CSS stylesheet. don't know why non-dynamic styles are being managed in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Place the images absolute in a relative placed table cell:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
td img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      text
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x20" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```